# Money Tax and Tip Float Complication

Tags: python, python-2.7, currency, raw-input

I am making a program to find the taxed amount of money and combine that with the tip.

I am working on the tipped amount and intro.

Code:

```
print "Welcome \nEnter The Amount Of Money For the Transaction"

amount = raw_input

print "Taxed Amount Below\n"
taxed = (amount * float((1.065)))

print taxed
```

And this is what I get out:

```
>>> runfile('/home/meyer/.spyder2/temp.py', wdir='/home/meyer/.spyder2')
Welcome 
Enter The Amount Of Money For the Transaction
Taxed Amount Below

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/meyer/.spyder2/temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    taxed = (amount * float((1.065)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'
>>>
```

I know that I cant multiply by this float, but I cant find any other way. Even MPMath

I am using python 2.7

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: You need to call `raw_input`.  `amount = raw_input()`.  You should also make it a float (`raw_input` returns a string).  `amount = float(amount)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code did not work because you need parameters after `raw_input`, try the below:

```
print "Welcome \nEnter The Amount Of Money For the Transaction"

amount = float(raw_input())

print "Taxed Amount Below\n"
taxed = (amount * float((1.065)))

print taxed
```

Comment: Not a downvoter but I think you need to convert `amount` to `float` as well.

Comment: @student Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to multiply a built-in function by a floating point number. You must instead call the function to obtain a number:

```
amount = float(raw_input())
```

Comment: I think in addition to that, need to convert `amount` to `float` as well.

Comment: Yep, fixed that!